# embedded document save with id null

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document `tariffGrid` that contains an embedded document `subGrids`, when i save the document `TariffGrid`, the `id` of the embedded document is saved as null

i used `private ObjectId _id` for the embedded document but there still the same problem

```
@Document
public class TariffGrid {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<SubGrid> subGrids;

}

@Document
public class SubGrid {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8df1f9ccd0df45146817a6"),
    "subGrids" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "name" : "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to save the `SubGrid` as embedded document, there is no need of `@Document` and `@Id` on class of `SubGrid`.  So here you are calling `save()` on the object of `TariffGrid` right? so spring-data-mongo will generate unique "Id" before saving the document.  Spirng-data-mongo will not auto-generate id for emedded documents.
Suppose if you call one more repository `save()` method with the `SubGrid` object then,
it auto-generates `id` field since you have added annotations, but that means `SubGrid` will be saved in one more collection seperately and there it will have `id`.

I believe you have confused it to be same as in case of hibernate where it used to save the related entities also with the use of @oneToMany and CascadeType.  But it is not the case here in mongoDB and in case of embedded documents.